# R : foreach, %dopar%, and source

Tags: r, cron, doparallel, parallel-foreach

I am taking over a script made just to run other scripts. The code used to do so is the following :

```
cl <- makeCluster(detectCores() - 1)
registerDoParallel(cl, cores = detectCores() - 1)

dopar_output <- foreach(x=listExec, .errorhandling = "pass") %dopar% {
  source(x)
}
```

listExec being a vector with various script path.

I have been trying to update this to pass on a variable with the name of the script to be used for log purpose during each script execution, like so :

```
dopar_output <- foreach(x=listExec, .errorhandling = "pass") %dopar% {
  Script <- basename(gsub(".R","",x))      
  source(x)
}
```

The goal is to have a "Script" variable available in the environment while each script runs to make sure the name of the script and the name used in the logs are the same.
However, with the code above, the Script variable is written in the list dopar_output, where I cannot use it (or at least I don't know how to).

I'm open to any suggestions, my first try was to declare the Script variable within each script with the command :

```
basename(sys.frame(1)$ofile)
```

However, that does not seems to be working properly in my environment, being : 
The script is run by a master script, itself run through a Cron job, on a Unix server.

Comment: `Script` only exists in the environment on the worker. That is expected. Where do you want it instead? Would something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42250632/1412059) serve your purpose?

Comment: Hello, not that's not it. I want ot have a variable thet is the name of the script, whatever script it is, to use it within that script. In this question, I show how I tried to do that from the master script, but I have tried to do so directly in the script ran by the master script with no success either. I just need a way, while executing the script "Example.R" to declare a variable that will be "Example.R", and it need to work when running the script through the master script, itself executed with a Cron job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `system(...)` call to pass arguments through `commandArgs(...)`

```
# script1.R
val <- commandArgs(trailingOnly=TRUE)
writeLines(val, "out1.txt")

# script2.R
val <- commandArgs(trailingOnly=TRUE)
writeLines(val, "out2.txt")
```

Define the `arg`

```
listExec <- c("script1.R", "script2.R")
dopar_output <- foreach(x=listExec, .errorhandling = "pass") %dopar% {
  arg <- basename(gsub(".R", "", x))
  system(paste("Rscript", x, arg))
}
```

Output in `out1` and `out2`

```
# out1.txt
# script1

# out2.txt
# script2
```

Comment: Hi, just tried your suggestion, val becomes : /usr/lib64/R/bin/exec/R
--slave
--no-restore
-e
parallel:::.slaveRSOCK()
--args
MASTER=localhost
PORT=11545
OUT=/dev/null
TIMEOUT=2592000
XDR=TRUE  (don't know what to do with this either)

Comment: I'll delete this answer - I'll test out other options

Answer (score 0):

CPak solution works. Just for the record, I found another way that works with source : 
use the below function in any script you want to get the name/fullpath :

```
get.full.path.to.this.sourced.script = function() {    
  for(i in sys.nframe():1) {  # Go through all the call frames,
    # in *reverse* order.
    x = sys.frame(i)$ofile
    if(!is.null(x))               # if $ofile exists,
      return(normalizePath(x))  #  then return the full absolute path
  }
}
```